# I can't get any result out from my mysql data base when I try to use PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to use PDO for the first time but I can't get any result out. I've tryed several variants of script examples that I found but I don't get any result out. No errors either. This is my latest attempt.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8', 'myuser', 'mypass'); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);   

$sql = " SELECT * FROM pages WHERE seo=:seo "; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
$values= array( 'seo' => $_REQUEST['p1'] ); 
$stmt->execute($values); 
while($result = $stmt->fetch()){ 
echo $result['text']; 
}
```

Comment: there are no faults at glance. you have to verify if database contains any relevant data and if $_REQUEST['p1'] contains desired value

Comment: you have to also ensure that all possible errors are printed out. make sure error_reporting() is set to at least E_ALL level and display_errors configuration option is turned on

Comment: also try to print out some debugging info, i.e. some remark in various script parts like "we're here"

Comment: look at the mySql log file usually `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log` and check the query is appearing, if so paste into the mysql command prompt and check the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a column named "text" in your table? Are you sure that the value you're supplying for the bind parameter exists in the `seo` column of the `pages` table?

For debugging, I suggest you try modifying the query a bit, to see if you are returning any rows:

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE 1=1 OR seo=:seo LIMIT 10
```

Also, echo out that value you are supplying for the bind parameter:

```
echo "bind parameter value = ", $_REQUEST['p1'];
```

You might also try dumping out the results after the fetch:

```
var_dump($result);
```

That should help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thank you. It works now as long as $_REQUEST['p1'] is not empty, but I also have one row in the db where seo is empty and I want to get this row  when $_REQUEST['p1'] is empty. It workes when I use mysql_query(), but not when I use PDO. Can that be solved?